# Reference form objects in C# to avoid repeating code blocks

Tags: c#, object-reference

I've tried searching for this, but my problem might be I don;t know the correct terms to describe the problem.

I have a C# form, with a number of textbox objects.

At some I process the contents of each textbox in sequence as follows:

```
tbxStressCmd1.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
processCmd(tbxStressCmd1.Text);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( tbxStressWait1.text );
tbxStressCmd1.BackColor = Color.White;

tbxStressCmd2.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
processCmd(tbxStressCmd2.Text);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( tbxStressWait2.text );
tbxStressCmd1.BackColor = Color.White;
.
tbxStressCmd9.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
processCmd(tbxStressCmd9.Text);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( tbxStressWait9.text );
tbxStressCmd9.BackColor = Color.White;
```

I'd like to avoid the repitition and have something like:

```
// Pseudo Code
runCmd ( object tbxCmd, object tbxWait )
{
   tbxCmd.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
   processCmd(tbxCmd.Text);
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( tbxWait.text );
   tbxCmd.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

Then:

```
runCmd( tbxStressCmd1, tbxStressWait1 );
.
.
runCmd( tbxStressCmd9, tbxStressWait9 );
```

What is the correct way to reference textbox objects such that they can be passed to functions and used as in the above pseudo code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing a variable of type `TextBox` as `object` to the method, You are not passing the actual type. Which is here, I suppose, `TextBox`. If you don't pass the actual type, you can't manipulate the properties of that type. You will just see & deal with the type as if it was of the type you use to pass the argument which is `Object` here **Since TextBox derive from the base class `Object`**. You can take a look at `Object` class members. You can't see a `Text` property there :).
You can do this:

```
public void DoTheThing(TextBox txCmd, TextBox txWait){
    txCmd.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
    ProcessCmd(txCmd.Text);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(txWait.Text)
    txCmd.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

I'd like to finish with some notes:

1. First You can't pass a string value to
   `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep`. You should do something called
   `casting` or `type conversion`. You can search for these terms. To
   do that, `C#` provide you with a helper class [Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx). You can use the helper method `ToInt32` to convert the value in the `TextBox` to `Int32` value type.
2. If you want to implement a "waiting"  or "delay" effect, in a `UI` application or in a `UI-Thread` context. I suggest you use `Task.Delay` instead, and `await` the returned delay task, and mark your method with `async` modifier. This is called [Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud. The sleep/wait was another refinement I was looking to do after cleaning up this code.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this @InBetween, I've edited the answer. If you noticed unclear lines just let me know.

Comment: You are missing the point. Neither operation is a boxing or unboxing conversion; its a simple reference conversion. Boxing and unboxing only happens when a *value type* is involved. A `TextBox` is most definitely not a value type.

Comment: This was indeed stupid, from me!! I forget about the `TextBox` "class". I'm going to edit the answer right now!